# removing bad characters from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a small problem in my mysql database
i have a column name that contains a lot of bad characters , i've searched here and find only the way to remove non alphanumeric only 
buy i don't need that i need to keep commas and underscores and question marks ... 
i'll give you example of the bad characters "Canâ€™t unsee itâ€¦" when it should be "Cant unsee it"

can i replace this characters with mysql directly without using php ? tell me how because i'm terrible with regular expressions

Comment: define "bad characters", is that everything except A-Za-z and whitespaces, are numbers allowed, !?.- allowed and so on

Comment: a-z A-Z 0-9 ! ? , - _ ' " .  those are the allowed carachters

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mysql query to update and replace the text you want.

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

Comment: what expression should i use to keep only this charachters a-z A-Z 0-9 ! ? , - _ ' " .

Comment: is this right ?
update posts set name = replace(name,'','€,™,â,€,¦') where 1;